# check if array contains certain int BEFORE another int

Tags: java, arrays

I need to check if an array contains a 1 and then later in the array contains a 2.

What I have coded only checks if both are in there, not if one is before the other. How could I do this?

```
if(array[i] == 1)
    count++;
  else if(array[i] == 2)
    count++;
  }

  if(count > 1)
    System.out.print("true");
    else
     System.out.print("false");
```

Comparing the index of the values works!

```
    if (nums[i] == 1)
      value1 = i;
      else if(nums[i] == 2)
        value2 = i;
  }

   if (value2 > value1)
     System.out.print("true");
   else
    System.out.print("false");
```

Comment: your curly braces look a little off right now...I'm only seeing a closing curly brace and no opening curly braces

Comment: there is code above what i pasted, it works

Comment: Try calculating the index of the `1` and the `2` and compare them.  You might also want a check that allows you to break out of the loop if you find a `2` before the `1`, as there's no point in continuing the search

Comment: That's a good idea! Though make sure you find the index of the first 1, and of the last 2. Well, depends on the rules: is it okay to find a 2 and then a 1, as long as there is a subsequent 2? Or must there be a single 1, followed at some point by a single 2, and no other 1s and 2s in the array? Or etc?

Comment: As long as there is 1 and then a 2 later it doesn't matter what else there is. I will try coding for the index and comparing them. Thanks.

Comment: What should happen for the array [ 1, 2, 1 ]? The implementation above will return false, even though there is a 1 followed b a 2. Also, what have you initialised value1 and value2 to? Is it possible that the function will behave strangely if either a 1 or 2 isn't found?

Answer (score 1):

This oughta do it!

```
public void hasOneThenTwo(int[] a) {
    bool hasOne = false;
    for (int i = 0; i < a.length; ++i) {
        if (!hasOne && a[i] == 1) {
            hasOne = true;
        } else if (hasOne && a[i] == 2) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```